# Expanding $\sin(x) + x$ on Fourier series in $[0, 2\pi]$ for $2\pi$ period

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

How can I expand $\sin(x) + x$ on Fourier series in $[0, 2\pi]$ for $2\pi$ period?

This what I got from [Euler-Fourier formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition):

$a_0 = 2\pi$

$a_n = 0$

$b_n = \frac{-2}{n}$

This is final result that I've calculated:
$$\pi - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin{nx}$$

Unfortunately I see that it doesn't approximate $x + \sin{x}$ correctly.

Comment: Since your function does not have period $2\pi$ the Fourier series will not converge pointwise to the function. It will converge in $L^{2}$ sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I thought the Fourier series  should converge to exact values in range $(0; 2\pi)$.

Comment: NO, that is not true at all.  Even FS of continuous periodic functions need not converge pointwise and when the function is not even periodic the FS certainly need not converge to the function. The series need not converge to $f$ in the open interval either.

Comment: In general are there any ways to check how good the Fourier series approximates function? I know that we can manually choose some big n and calculate deviation but I'm looking for some smarter smarter way to do it.